# What are the chances in getting a PhD in a sepcific Professor, when I barely passed his elective?

Tags: phd, thesis, grades

This might look similar to other questions, but I considered mine is more specific.
I basically messed up, my grades in the whole Masters degree are completely average to  higher than average (not my take - have asked for evaluation) and there is this elective that I even retook to improve my grade and still got the same! The professor that teaches this course has also accepted me for a Master Thesis and I was planning to ask for a PhD after I finish my Master's next year, but now I don't know if this is going to be possible. I know that he accepted students that haven't even taken the course, but I got myself into the situation of getting a low grade twice and he knows that!

Has anybody been in this situation either as a student or a professor? How did it go?

Comment: Even if someone had a similar situation, it will always depend on the individual situation. So ask your prof and make a good case for yourself.

Comment: How is your master's thesis going? Is there time to do good work there before a decision has to be made about your PhD application?

Comment: To answer to the first question, I know that probably is the best solution, but knowing about othe people's experiences might help me.

Comment: For the second I have barely started, so there is still time to salvage, but i don't know how to approach the situation, as I wanted to ask for a most difficult and heavy workload in order to show my capabilities as a researcher and I am not sure how it will look like. Also I am in Europe so the deadlines are still far away. I was even considering going first to industry - research after uni to improve my chances with gaining experience.

Comment: Instead of asking for the "most difficult and heavy workload" (not a good idea!) just talk to them about your future plans. When I supervise a master's thesis, the information if someone wants to pursue an academic career or simply wants to get their degree done is very important for the whole (supervision) process etc. That way, you could e. g. see how you can structure the thesis to have a good chance to get a paper in a peer-reviewed journal out of it.

Comment: Ok thank you! Yeah , i will avoid addressing it like i said and take more of your approach.

Comment: I agree with the above: it's best to talk to your professor. Tell him now that you want to do a PhD and should orient your master's toward that. Then when the time comes to choose a PhD advisor, you can have that conversation then. Coursework and research are only loosely connected, so I don't think you are disqualified. In any case, for future reference, our site only takes "answerable" questions; we don't really do poll questions or speculation/"what are the odds" questions. We're a little different than most other sites; you can learn more in our [help]. Good luck!